# How is this style of pseudocode written in latex?

Tags: algorithms

[image]I want to create an algorithm using the algorithm package. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1NWl.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1NWl.png)

Comment: Have a look the `algorithm2e` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code copied directly from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Algorithms

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
$i\gets 10$\;
\eIf{$i\geq 5$}
{
    $i\gets i-1$\;
}{
    \If{$i\leq 3$}
    {
        $i\gets i+2$\;
    }
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Pseudocode with syntax highlighting]